# How to use SUM() with getMany() in TypeORM?

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

I'm trying to write a group by query with TypeOrm/PostgreSQL ("pg": "^8.3.3", "typeorm": "^0.2.25").

The SQL query I need to be run is:

```sql
SELECT
    ad_id,
    COUNT (impression_id) AS impressions
FROM
    Ad_impressions
GROUP BY
    ad_id
ORDER BY
    impressions
```

I've read all the documentation and searched a lot online, but couldn't get it to work. This was my best try:

```js
await getConnection()
  .getRepository(Ad_impressions)
  .createQueryBuilder('Ad_impressions')
  .select([
    'Ad_impressions.ad_id',
    'COUNT(Ad_impressions.impression_id) as count',
  ])
  .groupBy("Ad_impressions.ad_id")
  .orderBy('impressions', 'DESC')
  .getMany();
```

Comment: Have you solved this yet? I'm having a similar issue with getMany and aliases in select

Answer (score 0):

use getRawMany instead of getMany.

```
await getConnection().getRepository(Ad_impressions).createQueryBuilder('Ad_impressions').select([
'Ad_impressions.ad_id',
'COUNT(Ad_impressions.impression_id) as count',]).groupBy("Ad_impressions.ad_id").orderBy('impressions', 'DESC').getRawMany();
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue when I try to get `SUM`.

```
const photosSums = await dataSource
.getRepository(User)
.createQueryBuilder("user")
.select("user.id")
.addSelect("SUM(user.photosCount)", "sum")
.groupBy("user.id")
.getRawMany()

// result will be like this: [{ id: 1, sum: 25 }, { id: 2, sum: 13 }, ...]
```

`getRawMany()` and `getRawOne()` solve my problem.

[TypeOrm described here](https://typeorm.io/select-query-builder#getting-values-using-querybuilder)

Answer (score 0):

If you want use SUM() function in combination with .getMany() you could modify  your Ad_impressions entity by adding an additional column to represent the count with option {select: false}, in this way this column is used for calculation purposes but not selected by default in regular queries.
Here's how you can implement this

```
@Column({ select: false, nullable: true })
  count: string;
```

and then in query builder

```
await getConnection()
  .getRepository(Ad_impressions)
  .createQueryBuilder('ad_impressions')
  .select([
    'ad_impressions.ad_id',
    'COUNT(ad_impressions.impression_id) as ad_impressions_count',
  ])
  .groupBy('ad_impressions.ad_id')
  .orderBy('impressions', 'DESC')
  .getMany();
```

Comment: It's important to note that in select statement you should assign aliases in the following manner <entity alias>_<column name>